# Eclipse style search in VS 2010?

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-2010, search, grep

In Eclipse, when I search a project for a string, I get a nice little search results box that shows every file that contains that string, along with the file system hierarchy.

In VS2010, when I search a project for a string, I have to click "next" through each appearance of the string, and sometimes don't realize I'm in a loop when it keeps jumping back and forth between the same locations.

Is there an equivalent to the Eclipse style search for VS2010?  I know that there's Find Symbol, but that doesn't seem to search in aspx files.  I know I can use an external grep tool, but I'm hoping there's something within the IDE.

Is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Find in Files" will do a string search with brute force.

Edit => Find & Replace => Find in Files  or Ctrl+Shift+F

but often people use that when they really want "Navigate To" which is a quick symbol search (Ctrl+ ',')

Comment: Duh.  Can't believe I missed that.